# Startup script for a specific user on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, scripts

Here is the command I want to be run at startup:

```
VBoxHeadless -s "pfsense"
```

as user "enedene".
Could someone give me step by step instructions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

1. Edit `/etc/rc.local`.
2. Add this to the bottom of the file:

   ```
   su -c 'VBoxHeadless -s "pfsense"' enedene &
   ```